# How to convert JavaPairRDD into HashMap

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a JavaPairDStream containing key-value pair. I need to convert it into a HashMap.I have tried doing the same with a normal JavaPairRDD by calling "collectAsMap()" function on it and its working but when I am trying to do the same on DStream, it fails.

I am trying to achieve the same by converting "JavaPairDStream" into "JavaPairRDD" by using "foreachRDD" function and then after that I am using "collectAsMap()" function on the JavaPairRDD.

```
Map<String,String> value= new HashMap<String,String>();
            value=line.collectAsMap();

//Here "line" is a "JavaPairRDD<String,String>".
```

It does not give any compilation error but when I run the program then it fails and throws the error as below.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lscala.Tuple2;
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap(PairRDDFunctions.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.collectAsMap(JavaPairRDD.scala:464)
    at attempt1.CSV_Spark$3.call(CSV_Spark.java:109)
    at attempt1.CSV_Spark$3.call(CSV_Spark.java:1)
```

I am not sure if my method is correct or not. Is there any difference between a normal "JavaPairRDD" and the one created by "foreachRDD" function? Why the same method works on a normal "JavaPairRDD" but fails when I am applying it on "JavaPairRDD" created by applying "foreachRDD" function on JavaPairDStream. If I am going wrong anywhere then kindly let me know. Also if there is any other way then please post it here. Thanks.

Comment: can you please include how did you apply the transformation from JavaPairDStream  to  JavaPairRDD with the foreachRDD function, I guess that there is the reason

Comment: Well, pairDStream is a sequence of pairRDD so when we use foreachRDD on a pairDStream then we can break it down into pairRDDs and do any  kind of operation on each RDD. But anyways the issue in my question posted above is actually a known bug. Check here[https://spark-project.atlassian.net/browse/SPARK-1040]. So I have resolved this issue by working on my own work-around solution. Its working perfectly.

Comment: OK, Great, this is the right link to the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1040, yours have a "]"

Comment: yeah. typing error. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At compile time, down casting is accepted as both **Map** and **HashMap** are in same inheritance. Although we dont get any compile time errors, we will get ClassCastException at run time. To avoid this problem, you could try this:

Code:

```
JavaPairRDD<K, V> javaRDDPair  = rddInstance.mapToPair(new PairFunction<T, K, V>() {
   @Override
    public Tuple2<K, V> call(final T value) {
    // statements 
    // operations on value
    return new Tuple2<K, V>(KTypeValue, VTypeValue);
    }
    });

    Map<K,V> map =  javaRDDPair.collectAsMap();
    HashMap<K,V> hmap = new HashMap<K,V>(map);
```

Note: *rddInstance* is an object of **JavaRDD** type .

Let's say we have a **JavaRDD** which holds **T** *type* values in it. 
upon transform on it, we create **JavaPairRDD** which holds <**K,V**> *pairs* .
Now the requirement is that convert JavaPairRDD to HashMap object for further computations in your application. Use *collectAsMap* method and assign its result to **Map** object itself. After that, you can create **HashMap** by passing **Map** *instance* .

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
JavaPairDStream stream =... 
JavaPairRDD pairRdd=stream.compute(validTime);
```

which is equivalent of a kind of bucketing around validTime instants of type Time , as you are reasoning on a stream.

Or, using forEachRDD, then wrap

```
JavaPairRDD<K,V> wrapRDD(RDD<scala.Tuple2<K,V>> rdd)
```

from there collectAsMap.

```
java.util.Map<K,V>  collectAsMap()
```